# Netty HTTP/2 client failing when connecting to https://http2.golang.org/

Tags: java, netty, http2

I'm very new to Netty and I'm still learning the basics. As part of the experiments I'm running, I decided to take the example Http2Client (https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http2/helloworld/client/Http2Client.java) and to try to connect to https://http2.golang.org/

However, this resulted in the following error:

```
.............. io.netty.handler.ssl.ApplicationProtocolNegotiationHandler handshakeFailure
WARNING: [id: 0xb57e60d4, L:/[MY-IP-IS-HERE]:59092 - R:http2.golang.org/130.211.116.44:443] TLS handshake failed:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: error:10000438:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.shutdownWithError(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:897)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.sslReadErrorResult(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1147)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1101)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1169)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1212)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$1.unwrap(SslHandler.java:216)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1297)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeNonJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1211)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1245)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:502)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:441)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:278)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:644)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:579)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:897)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have the following dependencies in the Maven pom:

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
     <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
     <version>4.1.30.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
     <artifactId>netty-codec-http</artifactId>
     <version>4.1.30.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
     <artifactId>netty-codec-http2</artifactId>
     <version>4.1.30.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
     <artifactId>netty-tcnative-boringssl-static</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.19.Final</version>
     <classifier>${os.detected.classifier}</classifier>
     <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>
```

`${os.detected.classifier}` resolves to `windows-x86_64`.

By the way, everything works when I connect the example Http2Client to the example Http2Server (https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http2/helloworld/server/Http2Server.java). It also works when I connect the example HttpSnoopClient (https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/snoop/HttpSnoopClient.java) to the example Http2Server.

So, is this a problem in Netty? Or in netty-tcnative-boringssl-static? Or in http2.golang.org? Or in my setup?

I'll appreciate any clues on the matter.

Comment: Because you are trying to connect over the ssl to https://http2.golang.org/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I don't understand why SSL is a problem. Browsers can connect to https://http2.golang.org successfully, so the server apparently supports SSL. Netty's example HTTP/2 server also supports SSL and browsers connect to it successfully via https. And Netty's example HTTP/2 client connects to Netty's example HTTP/2 server successfully over SSL. The problem can't be with certificates because (1) the client uses `InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE` and (2) the error doesn't say anything about bad certificates.
Can you, please, tell me why you think SSL is the problem?

Comment: Because it is a`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException`

Comment: Yes, it's a `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException`, but that alone doesn't mean that SSL is not supported. It only indicates that the error happens during SSL handshake. Browsers manage to do the SSL handshake, so clearly https://http2.golang.org supports SSL. So, one would expect that Netty will manage to connect over SSL too. I'd like to find out why Netty  (or the ALPN library used by Netty) fails to perform the handshake. It could be a bug in, say, the ALPN library, or in the https://http2.golang.org server, or I may have misconfigured something.

Comment: You could check which ciphers you have enabled. According to this bug https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/5859 jetty used to have defaults that made it incompatible with many sites - including those used by http2.golang.org. Though it does say it’s fixed in the version of Netty you are using but maybe that’s not correct or I’m reading it wrong...

Comment: It doesn't look like a problem with the ciphers. When I go to https://http2.golang.org/ via Firefox, I see the following in the Network tab: `Cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`. This same cipher is among the ones used by Netty's example Http2Client when trying to connect to that server (after applying `SupportedCipherSuiteFilter.INSTANCE`). By the way, I haven't made any modifications to the client except pointing it to https://http2.golang.org/. Code at https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http2/helloworld/client/Http2Client.java